# Is there a UISegmented control alternative for cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uisegmentedcontrol, kobold2d

Is there a UISegmented control for cocos2d. I know I can use the UISegmented control in cocos2d but I can only attach it to the glview and I need to be able to attach it to specific layers.

Comment: I could really use some help on this one.

Comment: Just show/hide the layers that you want, or make different scenes for each button and replace the scene on the director.

Comment: Agree, just show/hide one of multiple layers. CCLayerMultiplex might help in this case.

Comment: A segmented control is just several buttons together. You can make cocos2d analog yourself, using, say, CCMenuItemToggle.